# Drawing a square with colored hatched little subsquares

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I would like to draw a  as shown below. It is a square grid. Some regions are hatched in blue, others contain a red cross. Some edges are blue, others are red, but the red color don't reach the vertices, it stops just short of them, revealing the underlying thin black grid. Some vertices are colored red, others are colored blue.

I think I can draw the underlying grid myself, either by manually entering coordinates and instructions to link vertices by straight edges or using the `grid` command, and I think I should also be able to draw colored thick nodes that cover up whatever they lie on top of. however, I don't know how to draw the "hatched" region.

I want to include this drawing to lecture notes on homotopy theory I'm typing up. One defines a function by some fixed expression on the blue part of the grid, and inductively extends it to the whole square, first on the red vertices, then on the red edges, and lastly on the faces containing a red cross.

Thanks for your help!

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: It seems the pattern library will be useful.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you want to input the data. This is easily doable with TikZ but I’m guessing you want not to create each diagram from scratch. I see: a grid (is this squared-based or line-based?), blue lines making a filling, blue and red dots on the crossings of the grid, blue lines (without filling), red lines (that do not touch the crossings of the grid).

Comment: Could you provide a starting point in the form of your efforts so far?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With PSTricks just for fun! The remaining tedious parts can be easily added by yourself.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt,strokeopacity=.25}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](8,8)
    \multips(0,.5)(0,1){8}{%
        \multips(.5,0)(1,0){8}{%
            \psline[linecolor=red](6pt;-135)(6pt;45)
            \psline[linecolor=red](6pt;135)(6pt;-45)}}
    \pscustom
    [
        dimen=middle,
        fillstyle=eovlines*,
        fillcolor=white,
        hatchcolor=blue,
        linecolor=blue,
    ]
    {
        \psframe(8,8)
        \pspolygon
        (3,1)
        (3,4)
        (1,4)
        (1,6)
        (2,6)
        (2,7)
        (7,7)
        (7,4)
        (6,4)
        (6,6)
        (5,6)
        (5,4)
        (6,4)
        (6,3)
        (7,3)
        (7,1)
        (6,1)
        (6,2)
        (5,2)
        (5,1)
    }
    \psset{linecolor=blue,nodesep=7pt}
    \pscircle*(4,2){2pt}
    \pscircle*(4,3){2pt}
    \pcline(4,2)(4,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### update

here is my response to barbara beeton's comment:

[image]

Comment: This is just what I need, thank you! But when I copy and paste this into my existing file, it doesn't work, it doesn't work either when I paste the whole text in a new tex document. I get the error message `l.10 ...\psline[linecolor=red](6pt;135)(6pt;-45)}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed`

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the check mark button on the left. Optionally, upvoting it. :-)

Comment: I spy some indented code :) Just out of curiosity, did you run it through `latexindent`? oh, and +1, of course :)

Comment: no big deal- I tested `latexindent.pl` and it worked as expected :) might save you lots of tabbing in the future :)

Comment: is my browser sick, or are bits missing: the underlying black grid, the colored vertices, and the shorter rules along segments of the grid?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: thank you for upvoting. the more contrast grid has been added.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

`MWE` with `Asymptote`:

```
% topo.tex :
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{asydef}
import patterns;

struct topoBoxPens{
  pen gridPen, borderPen, outlinePen, hatchPen;
  pen crossPen, redStrokePen, blueStrokePen; 
  pen labelPen, bgPen;
  void operator init(
    pen gridPen=darkblue+0.4bp 
   ,pen borderPen=deepblue+2bp 
   ,pen outlinePen=deepblue+1bp 
   ,pen hatchPen=paleblue+2bp
   ,pen crossPen=red+1.2bp 
   ,pen redStrokePen=  deepred+3bp+opacity(0.7) 
   ,pen blueStrokePen=deepblue+squarecap+3bp+opacity(0.7) 
   ,pen labelPen=olive+fontsize(10pt)
   ,pen bgPen=paleyellow //white
  ){
    this.gridPen       = gridPen      ;           
    this.borderPen     = borderPen    ; 
    this.outlinePen    = outlinePen   ; 
    this.hatchPen      = hatchPen     ; 
    this.crossPen      = crossPen     ; 
    this.redStrokePen  = redStrokePen ; 
    this.blueStrokePen = blueStrokePen; 
    this.labelPen      = labelPen     ; 
    this.bgPen         = bgPen        ; 
  }
}

struct topoBox{
  int n; 
  real cellWidth;
  topoBoxPens Pens;
  pair ll, ur;
  int[][] mask;
  real dc;
  pair[] redDots;
  pair[] blueDots;
  guide[] redStrokes;
  guide[] blueStrokes;    

  void drawGrid(){
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
      draw((0,i)*cellWidth--(n,i)*cellWidth,Pens.gridPen);
      draw((i,0)*cellWidth--(i,n)*cellWidth,Pens.gridPen);
    }
  }  

  void drawGridLabels(){
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
      label("$"+string(n-i)+"$",(0,i+0.5)*cellWidth,W,Pens.labelPen);
      label("$"+string(n-i)+"$",(n,i+0.5)*cellWidth,E,Pens.labelPen);
      label("$"+string(i+1)+"$",(i+0.5,0)*cellWidth,S,Pens.labelPen);
      label("$"+string(i+1)+"$",(i+0.5,n)*cellWidth,N,Pens.labelPen);
    }    
  }  

  void drawBorder(){
    draw(box(ll,ur),Pens.borderPen);
  }  

  void drawHatch(){
    add("hatch",hatch(2mm,Pens.hatchPen));
    fill(box(ll,ur),pattern("hatch"));    
  }  

  guide[] xcross(transform t){
     return t*((-dc,-dc)--(dc,dc))
      ^^(t*((dc,-dc)--(-dc,dc)));
  }

  void drawMask(){

    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
      for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
        if(mask[i][j]==1){
          filldraw(
            box((j,n-i-1)*cellWidth,(j+1,n-i)*cellWidth)
            ,Pens.bgPen,Pens.gridPen
          );
        }
      }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
      for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
        if(mask[i][j]==1){
          draw(xcross(shift(j+0.5,n-i-0.5)),Pens.crossPen);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void drawOutline(){
    for(int i=1;i<n-1;++i){
      for(int j=1;j<n-1;++j){
        if(mask[i][j]==1 && mask[i-1][j]==0){
          draw((j,n-i)--(j+1,n-i),Pens.outlinePen);
        }
        if(mask[i][j]==1 && mask[i+1][j]==0){
          draw((j,n-i-1)--(j+1,n-i-1),Pens.outlinePen);
        }
        if(mask[i][j]==1 && mask[i][j-1]==0){
          draw((j,n-i)--(j,n-i-1),Pens.outlinePen);
        }
        if(mask[i][j]==1 && mask[i][j+1]==0){
          draw((j+1,n-i)--(j+1,n-i-1),Pens.outlinePen);
        }
      }
    }    
  }

  void drawDots(){
    for(int i=0;i<redDots.length;++i){
      fill(circle((redDots[i].x,n-redDots[i].y),2dc),Pens.redStrokePen);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<blueDots.length;++i){
      fill(circle((blueDots[i].x,n-blueDots[i].y),2dc),Pens.blueStrokePen);
    }
  }  

  void drawStrokes(){
    for(int i=0;i<redStrokes.length;++i){
      draw(reflect((0,n/2),(n,n/2))*subpath(redStrokes[i],0.2,0.8),Pens.redStrokePen);
    }    
    for(int i=0;i<blueStrokes.length;++i){
      draw(reflect((0,n/2),(n,n/2))*subpath(blueStrokes[i],0,1),Pens.blueStrokePen);
    }    
  }

  void draw(){
    drawGrid();
    drawGridLabels();
    drawHatch();
    drawMask();
    drawDots();
    drawStrokes();
    drawOutline();
    drawBorder();
  }

  void copyMask(int[][]mask){
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
      if(mask.initialized(i)){
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
          if(mask[i].initialized(j)){
            this.mask[i][j]=mask[i][j];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }    


  void operator init(
     int n=8
    ,int[][] mask
    ,pair[] redDots
    ,pair[] blueDots    
    ,guide[] redStrokes
    ,guide[] blueStrokes    
    ,real cellWidth=1
    ,topoBoxPens Pens=topoBoxPens()
  ){
    assert(n>1);
    this.n=n;
    this.mask=array(n,array(n,0));
    copyMask(mask);    
    this.redDots  = copy(redDots );
    this.blueDots = copy(blueDots);
    this.redStrokes  = copy(redStrokes);
    this.blueStrokes = copy(blueStrokes);
    this.Pens=Pens;
    this.cellWidth=cellWidth;
    this.ll=(0,0);
    this.ur=(n,n)*cellWidth;
    this.dc=0.0618cellWidth;
  }
}
\end{asydef}
%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";

size(200);

topoBox tb=topoBox(
  mask=new int[][]{
    array(8,0),
    new int[]{0,0,1,1,1,1,1,},
    new int[]{0,1,1,1,1,0,1,},
    new int[]{0,1,1,1,1,0,1,},
    new int[]{0,0,0,1,1,1,},
    new int[]{0,0,0,1,1,1,1,},
    new int[]{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,},
    }
  ,redDots=new pair[]{(3,2),(4,3),(4,4),(5,5)}
  ,blueDots=new pair[]{(2,3),(3,3),(4,2),(4,5),(4,6)}
  ,redStrokes=new guide[]{
     (2,2)--(3,2)
    ,(3,2)--(4,2)
    ,(4,2)--(5,2) 
    ,(6,2)--(7,2)
    ,(1,3)--(2,3)
    ,(3,3)--(4,3)
    ,(4,3)--(5,3)
    ,(6,3)--(7,3)
    ,(3,4)--(4,4)
    ,(4,4)--(5,4)
    ,(4,5)--(5,5)
    ,(5,5)--(6,5)
    ,(6,6)--(7,6)
    ,(2,2)--(2,3)
    ,(2,3)--(2,4)
    ,(3,1)--(3,2)
    ,(3,2)--(3,3)
    ,(3,3)--(3,4)
    ,(4,2)--(4,3)
    ,(4,3)--(4,4)
    ,(4,4)--(4,5)
    ,(4,6)--(4,7)
    ,(5,1)--(5,2)
    ,(5,4)--(5,5)
    ,(5,5)--(5,6)
    ,(6,1)--(6,2)
    ,(6,5)--(6,6)
   }
  ,blueStrokes=new guide[]{
    (4,1)--(4,2)
   ,(4,5)--(4,6)
   ,(2,3)--(3,3)
   ,(3,5)--(4,5)   
   ,(3,6)--(4,6)
   ,(4,6)--(5,6)
   }
);
tb.draw();
\end{asy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
%
% Process:
%
% pdflatex topo.tex    
% asy topo-*.asy    
% pdflatex topo.tex
```